# Rails: When deleting a session (wrong number of arguments)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, session

For some reason when I try to delete my session variable. I get "wrong number of arguements" error. Can you help me identify what is wrong.

Setting variable:

```
session[:account_edit] ||= [] 
session[:account_edit] << true
```

Trying to delete session variable:

```
if session[:account_edit]
  @edited = true
  session.destroy(:account_edit)
end
```

Error:

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

Comment: apparently you have a local variable or method `session`,so you do not get the right exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if session[:account_edit]
  @edited = true
  session.delete(:account_edit)
end
```

Ruby delete method [Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-delete)